# Passing Values with multiple buttons in React

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to learn react and I am trying to create a calculator. And the problem that I'm facing right now is trying to pass multiple values on a form. Every button press that I do always replaces the previous value.

so the gist of my form goes like:

```
<form action="" className='formCalc'>
          <input type="text" readOnly placeholder={input}/>
          <button className='num1' value='1' onClick={sample}>1</button>
          <button className='num2' value='2' onClick={sample}>2</button>
          <button className='num3' value='3' onClick={sample}>3</button>
          <button className='num4' value='4' onClick={sample}>4</button>
          <button className='num5' value='5' onClick={sample}>5</button>
          <button className='num6' value='6' onClick={sample}>6</button>
          <button className='num7' value='7' onClick={sample}>7</button>
          <button className='num8' value='8' onClick={sample}>8</button>
          <button className='num9' value='9' onClick={sample}>9</button>
          <button className='num0'value='0' onClick={sample}>0</button>
          <button className='clr' value='c' onClick={clrBtn}>C</button>
          <button className='eql' value='=' onClick={operateBtn}>=</button>
          <button className='pls' value='+' onClick={operateBtn}>+</button>
          <button className='min' value='-' onClick={operateBtn}>-</button>
          <button className='mul' value='*' onClick={operateBtn}>*</button>
          <button className='div' value='/' onClick={operateBtn}>/</button>
          <button className='dot' value='.' onClick={dotBtn}>.</button>


</form>
```

and the sample function goes something like:

```
const [input,setInput] = useState('');
const sample = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const value = e.target.value;
        setInput((input)=>{
          return [...input,value];
        });
    }
```

Unfortunately the best I can think of is using the `return [...input,value];` in the function. And that's not really doing what I want to do.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? Kindly give me more info

Comment: I am making a calculator, I have buttons from 0-9 and what I want is when I press a button, the value would be stored continously, and it stops and moves to a second const value when I press an operator.

Comment: Did you try out my answer? Please consider giving feedback, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `join('')` your array in a `useEffect()` (don't forget to import) to join the separate numbers so that you become a string.

If you would want to do calculations with these values later on, make sure you parse the string to an `int` or `float`.

Pass input in the `useEffect` dependency array so it updates every time the input changes.

```js
const [input, setInput] = useState([]); // store as array

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(input.join("")); // join to string
  }, [input]);

  const sample = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const value = e.target.value;
    setInput([...input, value]);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you store the value of pressed buttons as string. For example: "3+4+5-2". When you click operator "=", you can perform check-in the expression and perform calculate using [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) (Warning: it can be dangerous) or a third-party library